# Why is there a syntax error in my Python function?

Tags: python, function

```
number=list(map(lambda x:int(x), input().split()))

first=".|."
second='-'
median=((number[0]-1)//2)+1

def Door(number[0],number[1]): # <<-- this one is resulting in a syntax error.
```

So I still fail to understand what is wrong with this code.
Can you please help me?
Thank you.

Comment: Because a value cannot be a parameter. It require an identifier. What do you even expect this to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line:

```
def Door(...):
```

you are *defining* a function. You define a function with variables as parameters. When you *call* the function you pass it values.

What I think you are planning to do is first define `Door()` and then later call it with the values `number[0]` and `number[1]`.

So begin your definition of the function like this:

```
def Door(a,b):
```

and when you want to call it, *then* you pass it the values `number[0]` and `number[1]`, like this:

```
mydoor = Door(number[0],number[1])
```

Then, inside `Door()`, when your code refers to `a` and `b`, it is using the values of 
`number[0]` and `number[1]`. This disconnect is so that the function can be called from different places with different parameters.

This applies even if you are defining the function just to modularize your code, and you only ever plan to call it from one place.

Comment: Now i got what is the problem of my code. Thank you so much for your detailed explanation. Really Helpful :D